# Infopath: adding a date field and a number field to return new date

Tags: forms, infopath

I hope someone can help.

In my InfoPath form I have a date field and a number field (this number field represents a year, so if the value is 1 then it equals 1 year).

I want to add these two fields to give me a new date.  I've tried but I just get a return value of NaN, as you'd expect.

Please can someone help me with the calculation so I get a date value?

If it helps, the calculation I have tried so far is:

../my:field8 + (../my:field22 * 365)

Thank you.

Comment: What does the actual value of your my:field22 field look like? Is it a date in a format like `2017-01-13`, or something else?

Comment: Thank you.  I have managed to achieve this by adding the addDays;

Comment: xdDate:AddDays(../my:field8, (../my:field22 * 365))